# Find all $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $\sin(z) =a$

Tags: complex-analysis

Unlike the real sine function, the complex sine function is not bounded.
Find all $z \in \Bbb C$ such that $$$$
$$\sin(z) =a$$ 
$$$$
I have a myriad of questions where $a$ is replaced with natural and rational numbers but I am struggling with the fundamentals. Is there a quick proof I could apply to my work so I can practice and practice until it's etched into my brain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$\sin(z)=a$ means $e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=2ai$. Set $w= e^{iz}$, so $w$ solves
$$w^2-2ai w-1=0.$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: I believe so, I am using the quadratic formula to find $w$ and it seems I have to soon substitute back for $e^{iz}$  and work with natural logs. Thanks for the step in the right direction.

Comment: What solution should I use for Ln(i)? I don't think $\frac {\pi}{2}i$ is correct.

Comment: $\pi i/2$ is one possible value for $\log(i)$. But so is $\pi i/2 + 2k \pi$ for any $k \in \mathbb Z$. This reflects the fact that $e^{iz}$ is a periodic function. You should be fine as long as you take this into account.